# Cannot download generated PDF file hosted in xampp

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, pdf

I've decided to ask about this issue because is driving me crazy and I don't know what can I do because I tried everything I can think of.

I'm building a web tool with laravel. There's an option to generate some reports in pdf and here is when my problem starts.

My functions to build this pdf file are.

```
public function generarPDF() {

        $inicio = Input::get('inicio');
        $fin = Input::get('fin');

        $datos = $this->datosInforme($inicio, $fin);

        $html = View::make('reportes.pdf', array('datos' => $datos,
                                                   'inicio'=> $inicio,
                                                   'fin' => $fin));

        return $html;

    }

    public function descargarArchivoPDF() {

        $inicio = Input::get('inicio');
        $fin = Input::get('fin');

        $nombreArchivo = storage_path().'/pdf/report-'.(new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d').'.pdf';

        if (file_exists($nombreArchivo)) {
            unlink($nombreArchivo);
        }

        $command = 'wkhtmltopdf -O Landscape -s A4 -T 25 -R 20 -B 25 -L 20 "';

        $url = url('/generar-pdf-reporting');
        $argumentos = array();

        if (!empty($inicio)) {
            $argumentos[] = 'inicio='.$inicio;
        }

        if (!empty($fin)) {
            $argumentos[] = 'fin='.$fin;
        }

        if (count($argumentos) > 0) {
            $argumentos = '?'.implode('&', $argumentos);
        }
        else {
            $argumentos = '';
        }

        $url .= $argumentos;

        $command .= $url.'" '.$nombreArchivo;

//        return $command;

        $process = new Symfony\Component\Process\Process($command);

        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        else {
            return Response::download($nombreArchivo);
        }

    }
```

generarPDF function just builds a view which will be the content of the pdf file.

The file is created successfully but when I try to download it, I cannot do it because (according to chrome) there's a network error.

Weird thing is that everything works fine in my linux box, which does not use xampp but apache+php+mysql installed from repositories.

If I remove the code to build the file and leave only the one to download a former created one, works flawlessly so, I thought it could be a matter of Symfony Process running asynchronously, so made it wait until finished but with no luck.

xampp is installed in a Windows 8 server.

I don't know what else I can do. Can be a xampp bug?

Comment: Does it throws any exception or your find anything in error.log ?

Comment: Nothing at all. Everything seems to work well. It's really strange.

Comment: Are you storing the generated pdf and pointing the link to it to download or just generating a link that generates and download pdf ?

Comment: When I click the button to generate the pdf file, the function creates the file and then makes the browser download it. That's why I use the "return Response::download()" function.

Comment: Why can't you generate a link on success event that points to generated pdf ?

Comment: Maybe that could be my last solution. I think it's better the user would click a button just once to have the file downloaded.

Comment: I have used this same case for my project, And i did the same what you expect.. You want me to explain how to do this logically ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94901/discussion-between-dhouard-and-sulthan-allaudeen).

Comment: I have update my answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Logical way, How i would handle it

**Step 1 :** First have a link like this

yourapp/generatepdf/14

It should be like this Click here

or

if you point directly to a file

Click here

i.e., 14 is the param that you pass

**Step 2 :** Inside your controller

Generate /Output a pdf based on the input param

**Step 3 :** So, once the link is opened it will generate and download the pdf with respect to your param

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying to put http header within the file ?

as mentioned in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-examples) for http header,

may you have to try this :

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

I'm not sure if the header is already exists in your code or not, CMIIW :-)

Comment: I tried sending headers and reading the file too. I think it's something related to xampp over windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$filename=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dirctory/your.pdf";
$realname="filename.pdf";
if (file_exists($filename))
    {
        // send headers to browser to initiate file download
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header ('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $realname . '"');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        readfile($filename);

    }
```